# facial feature extraction using OPENCV, python

Tags: python, opencv

i have been working on an project which requires to extract the facial features in python. I will be using openCV in this project too. I have found a deep learning model, is there any other way to extract facial features other than that?

Comment: please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, haar cascades don't work in this case. You can use this link: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/10/detect-eyes-nose-lips-jaw-dlib-opencv-python/

This uses a pretrained deep learning model that can be used. The features extracted are store / given in a list of coordinates. Hence they ca be manipulated by the opencv.

this model is very accurate and hepful.